# jQuery $.ajax only working on first click inside of $.click

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

So heres my problem.  On the first fire of my code it works perfect but I reload the submit button using javascript (rather then refreshing the page).  Everything that doesn't have to do with ajax runs fine on the second click but I can not for the life of me get the ajax to run the next time the button is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
$("#edit_company_basic").live('click', function()
    {
        //get current value of button
        var btnText = $("#submit_company_update").val();

//on click the button becomes disabled and value changes to Please Wait
        $("#submit_company_update").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#submit_company_update").attr("value", "Please wait");

//this one add a loader gif and a updating company message
        $('#button_container').append("<div id='update'><center><img id='loading' src='images/icons/ajax-loader (1).gif' />&nbsp;<font color='red'>Updating company</font></center></div>");


//These variables are used for the ajax datastring
        var name = $("#company_name").val();
        var bio = $("#company_bio").val();
        var forum_url = $("#forum_url").val();
        var collection = $("#collection :selected").text();
        var fuel = $("#fuel :selected").text();
        var repair = $("#repair :selected").text();
        var tickets = $("#tickets :selected").text();
        var dataString = 'company_name='+ name + '&bio=' + bio + '&forum=' + forum_url + '&collection=' + collection + '&repair=' + repair + '&fuel=' + fuel + '&ticket=' + tickets;  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "library/update_company.php",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function() 
            {  

//On success I give the loader a little more time before anything happens I then re-enable the button allowing the user to be able to click it and give them a message that the copmany has been successfully updated.
            setTimeout(function(){$("#submit_company_update").attr("value", btnText); $("#submit_company_update").removeAttr('disabled'); $("#update").html("<center><font color='green'>Company has been updated</font></center>"); }, 1550);

//Here I just give the company updated message a few seconds before I remove it.
                setTimeout(function(){$("#update").fadeOut(1000); }, 2200);
            }
        });  

    });
```

Here is my html that is involved in all that jscript

```
<tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="submit_form"><div id="button_container"><center><input type="submit" name="submit_company_update" id="submit_company_update" value="Edit Company" /></center></div></td>
        </tr>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make the ajax run again once the button is re-enabled?  Whats happening is once I re-enable the button to be clicked again it won't run the ajax.

Thanks in advance,

Jefffan24

**UPDATE**

So here is my whole javascript code from that page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#warning_price").hide();
$(".toggle_container").hide(); 

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
$("#company_name").click(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").toggleClass("active").slideDown("normal");
});
$("#company_name").blur(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").slideUp('normal');
});

//This displays a warning message if they don't have permission to this part of the site.
$("#noperm").html('<div class="ui-widget" style="width:650px; margin:0 auto;"><div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em; margin-top:3px;"></span><strong>Error:</strong><br /> That was a heck of try but you do not have permission to access this area.</p></div></div> ');


//This is a jQuery character count plugin, just setting options and what not
var options2 = {
'maxCharacterSize': 450,
'textFontSize': '12px',
'textColor': '#000000',
'warningColor': '#FF0000',
'originalStyle': 'originalDisplayInfo',
'warningStyle': 'warningDisplayInfo',
'warningNumber': 100,
'displayFormat': '#input Characters | #left Characters Left | #words Words'
};
var options1 = {
'maxCharacterSize': 255,
'textFontSize': '12px',
'textColor': '#000000',
'warningColor': '#FF0000',
'originalStyle': 'originalDisplayInfo',
'warningStyle': 'warningDisplayInfo',
'warningNumber': 40,
'displayFormat': '#input Characters | #left Characters Left | #words Words'
};
$('#company_bio').textareaCount(options2);
$('#company_name').textareaCount(options1);
$('#forum_url').textareaCount(options1);
//End the counter


//Create Select Boxes (using for loops to make 1-50, 1-90, and 1-90 as options
var minimum = 1;
var max_col = 50;
var max_assist = 90;
var i = 1;
var def_collection = <?php echo $collection; ?>;
var def_repair = <?php echo $repair; ?>;
var def_fuel = <?php echo $fuel; ?>;
var def_tickets = <?php echo $ticket; ?>;
//Select boxes for Collection
$("#tdCollection").append("<select id='collection' name='collection'>");



for(i = 1;i <= max_col; i++){
    if(i == def_collection){
        $("#collection").append("<option selected='selected'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
    else {
        $("#collection").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
    }
}
$("#tdCollection").append("</select>%");

//Select boxes for Repair
$("#tdRepair").append("<select id='repair' name='repair'>");
for(i = 1;i <= max_col; i++){
    if(i == def_repair){
        $("#repair").append("<option selected='selected'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
    else {
        $("#repair").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
    }
}
$("#tdRepair").append("</select>%");

//Select boxes for Fuel
$("#tdFuel").append("<select id='fuel' name='fuel'>");
for(i = 1;i <= max_col; i++){
    if(i == def_fuel){
        $("#fuel").append("<option selected='selected'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
    else {
        $("#fuel").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
    }
}
$("#tdFuel").append("</select>%");

//Select boxes for tickets
$("#tdTickets").append("<select id='tickets' name='tickets'>");
for(i = 1;i <= max_col; i++){
    if(i == def_tickets){
        $("#tickets").append("<option selected='selected'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
    else {
        $("#tickets").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
    }
}
$("#tdTickets").append("</select>%");

//End the select box code.

//On form submit!
$("#edit_company_basic").live('click', function()
{

    var btnText = $("#submit_company_update").val();
    $("#submit_company_update").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#submit_company_update").attr("value", "Please wait");
    $('#button_container').append("<div id='update'><center><img id='loading' src='images/icons/ajax-loader (1).gif' />&nbsp;<font color='red'>Updating company</font></center></div>");
    var name = $("#company_name").val();
    var bio = $("#company_bio").val();
    var forum_url = $("#forum_url").val();
    var collection = $("#collection :selected").text();
    var fuel = $("#fuel :selected").text();
    var repair = $("#repair :selected").text();
    var tickets = $("#tickets :selected").text();
    var dataString = 'company_name='+ name + '&bio=' + bio + '&forum=' + forum_url + '&collection=' + collection + '&repair=' + repair + '&fuel=' + fuel + '&ticket=' + tickets;  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "library/update_company.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() 
        {  
            setTimeout(function(){$("#submit_company_update").attr("value", btnText); $("#submit_company_update").removeAttr('disabled'); $("#update").html("<center><font color='green'>Company has been updated</font></center>"); }, 1550);
            setTimeout(function(){$("#update").fadeOut(1000); }, 2200);
        }
    });  

});
});


 </script>
```

And here is all my HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" name="edit_company_basic" id="edit_company_basic">
         <table class="company" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" style="width:550px; margin:0 auto;">
         <!--<tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="padding:0px;"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?> Logo" /></td>   
         </tr>-->
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="th_bold"><center>Basic Information</center></th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th width="120">Company Name:</th>
             <td width="400" valign="top"><input type="text" name="company_name" class="company_name" id="company_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" style="width:395px;" /><br />
            <div class="toggle_container">
                <div class="block">
                    <span id="warning_price" style="background:#FFF9F9; border:1px solid red; min-width:395px; width:395px; padding:5px;"><strong>Warning:</strong> Editing the name will cost the company $2000</span>
                </div>
            </div>


            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th valign="top">Company Bio:</th>
            <td width="400"><textarea name="company_bio" id="company_bio" style="width:390px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px; height:150px;"><?php echo $bio; ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Forum URL:</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="forum_url" id="forum_url" value="<?php echo $forum; ?>" style="width:395px;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Default Collection:</th>
            <td id="tdCollection"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Default Repair Assistance:</th>
            <td id="tdRepair"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Default Fuel Assistance:</th>
            <td id="tdFuel"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Default Ticket Assistance:</th>
            <td id="tdTickets"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="submit_form"><div id="button_container"><center><input type="submit" name="submit_company_update" id="submit_company_update" value="Edit Company" /></center></div></td>
        </tr>
         </table>
         </form>
```

If anyone sees anything let me know, there is some php in there but none of that is an issues I don't believe as the spots where it is used are not causing me any problems.

Comment: First `<font>` tag I've seen in a long, long time.

Comment: lol yeah when I need to change it fast I use font rather then css.

Comment: You can always use `style="color: red"` on any element you want

Comment: Yeah, thats true.  I mean I normally use css, classes and what not but it was just a couple words I wanted to turn red and I just did first thing that popped in my mind.  Every thing else on the site is css besides that red font and the green font it turns to later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use removeAttr to remove disabled, instead set it to false

```
$("#submit_company_update").attr('disabled', false);
```

Eric

Comment: That's good advice, but it's not really an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

Your "click" handler should return `false`. If it doesn't, then the normal action of the "submit" element will take place - the submittal of the form. That'll reload the page, and (I guess) your Javascript won't happen. (It's not really clear how or when the Javascript runs, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be applied after the page reload.)

Comment: Well I'm trying to eliminate the page reload, which is why I'm using Ajax. The form works without reloading the first time but if I click the button again the ajax never runs.  I was hoping for a way to make it work again and again without reloading the page.

Comment: Well, there's probably more going on here that in just the code you've posted. What sort of debugging have you done so far?

Comment: I don't really know where to put the debugging code, I mean I've used IE to see if it is throwing any errors and its not, but other then that not quite sure what to do.  I've posed all my Javascript and html code above under the bold update.

Answer (score 0):

I could never get this to work and I need to get it done so what I decided to do was forget ajax and just disable the button on click, and then submit with the standard

```
$("form id here").submit();
```

I use php from there, and then on reload it puts a nice message letting them know its been updated.

Thanks for all the help all I really appreciate it, and hopefully someday when I have time I can re-visit it and make it work ;)